# performing an animation, then display fields after animation finish Android

Tags: android, facebook, animation

I want to set my logo to appear at the middle when starting the app.
then it will move to the top, and when the animation finish, the fields and button(email, password, sign in button) will appear.

like the Facebook android app entry.

[image: facebook 1]

[image: facebook 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain animation programatically  by means of  an animationSet, and then add whatever you want at the end by means of AnimationListeners.

```
AnimationSet animationSet= new AnimationSet();

TranslateAnimation a = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.ABSOLUTE,FROM_X, Animation.ABSOLUTE,FROM_Y,
        Animation.ABSOLUTE,TO_X, Animation.ABSOLUTE,TO_Y);
a.setDuration(DURATION);
a.setFillAfter(true); 
animationSet.addAnimation(a);

TranslateAnimation b = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.ABSOLUTE,TO_X, Animation.ABSOLUTE,TO_Y,
        Animation.ABSOLUTE,TO_X2, Animation.ABSOLUTE,TO_Y2);
b.setDuration(DURATION2);
b.setFillAfter(true); 
b.setStartOffset(DURATION);
animationSet.addAnimation(b);


 //add all the animations that you need, having everyone starting in the position and the time where the last one ends.
//Then add a listener to last animation, or to the animationset and write the code you need to run when everything is finished in the onAnimationEnd function

 animationSet.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            //code to run when the animations are finished
            //for instance, if you have some views in your layout that where hidden
            View v= findViewById(R.id.YOUR_HIDDEN_VIEW;
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


       }


  });
```

If you dont know how to start the animation, you havr to call the startAnimation method of the view you want to animate.

```
 THE_LOGO.startAnimation(animationSet);
```

Update

In your edited question I can see that you only need one tranlation. So it is easier. Anyways you can still use the animationset, since the first animation could be a fade in with an alpha animation. Take a look at the posibilities here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the [animation listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) `onAnimationEnd`

Comment: can you provide me with an exemple of use ?

Answer (score 0):

Add an AnimationListener to your animation object like below

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            //The Function which you want to do before the animation starts

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            //Functions to be executed each repeat of the animation

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            //Functions to be executed at the end of animation

        }
    })
```